# python power shell issues

Tags: python, powershell

***Edited to include a specific example***

I am learning to use python and work in a windows 10 environment (although on 3 separate computers). I have gotten past the "add python to %PATH% issue" but continue to see odd outcomes when I call simple scripts from powershell compared to running them from the python terminal. For example, I often see that lines of code are duplicated, even simple print statements. A second repeating issue is that some (but not all) modules work fine in the python terminal but can't be found when running a script from powershell, despite using pip install within powershell to install it in the first place.

Rather then seeking help on a specific issue, I'm hoping for some guidance into how powershell and python interact that might help me understand or identify some commonalities in these issues I keep experiencing that are common from within powershell. If thats as simple as redirecting me towards another source even that'd be apprecaited. But my search results always turn up the common issue of powershell not knowing what python is, and needing to add python to the PATH. But as indicated, I have already gotten past this and can get %50 of my python to work from powershell. There must be something else perhaps obvious to others that I'm missing that can help me understand why some things aren't working while others are.

Thanks for taking the time to consider my problem and any advice is greatly apprecaited.

Here is an ***example*** from some code I am trying to get working, but in troubleshooting I have taken out a lot of code and am now only running what is shown that defines a dataframe and a print statement. Everything works line by line in python, but when I call the script from powershell, the print statement executes twice.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd

joedata = {'fpr': [0.2,0.4,0.8], 'tpr':[0.9,0.5,0.1]}

joeframe = pd.DataFrame(data=joedata)

print(joeframe)
```

Comment: This is way too broad. You *should* narrow it down to a specific issue.

Comment: Sorry for being too broad. I have included a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning modules, you probably have multiple versions of Python installed on your system. Calling pip in the Powershell doesn't mean that it will install for the Python installation which is called by default when you execute Python in the Powershell. So you should try to figure out on which version pip is installing packages and which version is actually used when executing a script.

**EDIT**: I tested the example that you gave in Powershell and I don't have the problem, it's working fine.

Moreover, for me, without doing any special configuration, in Powershell the commands `pip` and `python` refer to the same version of Python. If by default everything is ok, you should consider uninstalling Python and just running the installer again and let it manage the PATH, etc.

Comment: Ok I'll look into this and report back.

Comment: Edited my post in response to your edits. Everything's working fine for me.

Comment: Well I just figured out my issue, I had named the file ggplot.py which is  why I saw repeated pieces of code, as I was importing the same script I was practicing. In fact, I had named allot of files I was practicing with as "modulename.py", which explains ALLOT of my problems. Thanks for taking the time to consider my situation, although I'm certainly embarrassed that this was the source of my problems.